# Simple regular expression substitution crashes on Windows using regex-compat

Tags: windows, haskell, ghc

The following code crashes when using GHC on Windows. It works perfectly on Linux.

Does this make any sense or is there a bug?

```
module Main where

import qualified Text.Regex as Re -- from regex-compat
import Debug.Trace

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStr $ cleanWord "jan"
  putStr $ cleanWord "dec"
  putStr $ cleanWord "jun" -- crashes here

cleanWord :: String -> String
cleanWord word_ =
  let word = trace (show word_) word_ in
  let re = Re.mkRegexWithOpts "(jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)" True False in
  Re.subRegex re word ""
```

Some additional details

1. I'm building with `stack`
2. It crashes in both GHCi and running the compiled executable
3. I tried to enable profiling but can't seem to figure out how to get that to work correctly.

Comment: Also, what is the exception?

Comment: @Zeta updated, its regex-compat

Comment: @Alec program crashes, nothing in the console output.

Comment: @Alec, yup. Crashes with no output

Comment: It's a bug, probably in `regex-posix`, due to its difference in the inclusion of the underlying BSD regex library  from 1994. In `sslow`, an invalid memory address (`-1(%rdx)` with `rdx = 0`) will be accessed. I'm too tired for an in-depth analysis, but you could add `CC-Options: -g` and compile those packages by hand to find the culprit. Given that the package uses HSC doesn't make it a lot easier, to be honest…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shuffling the regex around avoids the bug in this case.

This works fine for me now

```
let re = Re.mkRegexWithOpts "(jul|aug|sep|oct|jun|nov|dec)" True False in
```

I.e. moving the `jun` towards the end of the regex. Not particularly satisfactory but it works and it means I can continue.

@Zeta's comment suggest that this is a bug with the underlying library

> It's a bug, probably in regex-posix, due to its difference in the
>   inclusion of the underlying BSD regex library from 1994. In sslow, an
>   invalid memory address (-1(%rdx) with rdx = 0) will be accessed.