# Text.Regex.Posix's =~ operator cannot get the return value in some patterns

Tags: regex, haskell, posix

Text.Regex.Posix's =~ operator cannot get the return value in some patterns.

For example,

```
> import Text.Regex.Posix
> "y2019m10d08" =~ "y([0-9]{4})?m([0-9]{1,2})?d([0-9]{1,2})?" :: Bool 
True
> "y2019m10d08" =~ "y([0-9]{4})?m([0-9]{1,2})?d([0-9]{1,2})?" :: Int 
1
> "y2019m10d08" =~ "y([0-9]{4})?m([0-9]{1,2})?d([0-9]{1,2})?" :: [[String]]
```

What I expected

```
[["y2019m10d08","2019","10","08"]]
```

But after the last entry, the calculation doesn't seem to end.

Why?

My environment:

- Windows 10
- GHC 8.6.5
- regex-base-0.93.2
- regex-posix-0.95.2

Comment: It works as you expected on macOS 10.14.6 with Stackage LTS 14.7 (GHC 8.6.5, regex-base-0.93.2, regex-posix-0.95.2).

Comment: It also works as you expected on Archlinux using the same GHC and package versions. I got the answer immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Given both the comments and the nature of the package, this is likely to be due to a bug in the underlying C library on your particular system which provides RegEx logic.

This is not the first bug specific to Windows reported for this package (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39047317/simple-regular-expression-substitution-crashes-on-windows-using-regex-compat/) and [here](https://github.com/haskell-hvr/regex-posix/issues/1)). You can open an issue on the `regex-posix` repository and see if they can find the culprit.